# for command does not allow move or xcopy command to move/copy the folder only the contents

Tags: wildcards, xcopy, move

have looked on this forum for several examples, started off with xcopy ( not allowing wildcards in the folder name ), wanted to pipe the dir command to either xopy or move but require the dir structure to be intact - bet it's a small syntax issue I do not see as I am not a batch file guru

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b /ad "source dir\*error.*"') do xcopy /y "%~a" "target dir"
```

do not know what the "delims=" is - i just grabbed it from a example

I replace xcopy with move but that just threw a error as it did not like spaces in the dir name even though the double quotes are there - thx

Comment: run `for /?` to know what `delims=` is. To get help for any cmd commands use `command /?`

Comment: th now if i could get a answer on why the directory structure is not being copied over that would be gold. I thought the for command was supposed to bypass the folder & wildard limits of xcopy

Comment: completely in a loop trying to figure this - how does $50 to anyone who can